# Can't stack SVG images on top of each other with css?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to stack to SVG images on top of each other but the behaviour I see is very weird.

I am using simple wrappers with position relative-absolute to stack them on top of each other.

What really baffles me is that the order seems to matter (not just for what is on top - but for how the images are displayed) even though they are positioned absolute. To my understanding two absolutely positioned elements do not influence each other.

Has someone encountered this behaviour before?

**Here is a coding [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-fast-wqpms) of my problem.**

**EDIT:** The problem does happen in Chrome but not in Safari.

The Sandbox results (strangely) in an error message so I am posting the code here:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ReactComponent as DottedBall } from "./dotted-ball.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Overlay } from "./index-overlay-1.svg";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "./styles.css";

const SVGWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <SVGWrapper>
          {/* wrapper I */}
          <DottedBall />
        </SVGWrapper>
        <SVGWrapper>
          {/* wrapper II - try putting before wrapper I */}
          <Overlay />
        </SVGWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
      <svg width="750" height="500" style="background: gray">
        <svg x="200" y="200">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: red" />
        </svg>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: yellow" />
      </svg>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I get an error in the Console going to that sandbox: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: really - there are no state updates in the sandbox that that error is rather weired ... I can open it without any problems in chrome and safari. Here is the written link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-fast-wqpms -- can you check again?